# Error with a linked list data structure

Tags: c

I have a problem while compiling this c program, that create a linked list structure and makes the user insert values at the beginning or at the end of the list. 
While compiling I get this error:

```
    list.c: In function ‘list_insert_up’:
    list.c:49:6: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘list_t’ from type ‘struct list_t *’
    *ptr=allocate(ptr);
enter code here
```

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct list_t{
    int val;
    struct list_t *next;

};

typedef struct list_t list_t;

list_t *head=NULL;
list_t *curr=NULL;

// FUNCTIONS

list_t*
allocate(list_t *ptr){
    return malloc(sizeof(list_t));
}

void
deallocate(list_t *ptr){
    free(ptr);
}

list_t*
list_block_create(list_t *ptr, int value){
    list_t *curr=ptr;
    ptr->val=value;
    ptr->next=NULL;
    head=curr=ptr;
    printf("--Block created successfully!--\n");
}

void
list_print(list_t *ptr){
    size_t i=0;
    while(ptr!= NULL){
        printf("%i\n",ptr->val);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    printf("--List printed successfully!--\n");
}

list_t*
list_insert_up(list_t *ptr,int value){
    *ptr=allocate(ptr);
    ptr->val=value;
    ptr->next=head;
    head=ptr;

}


// MAIN

int
main(){

    list_t *ptr=allocate(ptr);

    list_block_create(ptr,1);
    list_print(ptr);
    list_insert_up(ptr,2);
    list_print(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the argument in this function if it isn't used: `allocate(list_t *ptr){` ?

Comment: Yes you're right, i will remove the argoment.

Comment: list_block_create() returns a list_t*, except that it doesn't.

Comment: Do you know why I get this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix a few things:

It is confusing your use of `curr`, first defining it as a global variable, and then masking it inside `list_block_create`. This is probably not what you want.

And

```
list_t*
allocate(){
    return (list_t*) malloc(sizeof(list_t));
}
```

And

```
list_t*
list_insert_up(list_t *ptr,int value){
    list_t* ptr2=allocate();
    ptr2->val=value;
    ptr2->next=ptr->next;
    ptr->next=ptr2;
    return ptr2;  /* not really needed, the function might return void */
}
```

And actually use instead of `list_insert_up`

```
list_t*
list_insert_top(int value){
    list_t* ptr=allocate();
    ptr->val=value;
    ptr->next=head;
    head=ptr;
    return ptr;  /* not really needed, the function might return void */
}
```

And

```
list_t*
list_block_create(list_t *ptr, int value){
    head=ptr;
    ptr->val=value;
    ptr->next=NULL;
    printf("--Block created successfully!--\n");
    return ptr;  /* not really needed, the function might return void */
}
```

You would be probably better off changing a little bit the logic of your code, e.g., removing global variables. If you do this, you would probably need to keep the return values of your functions (what I quoted as not needed, as things are now).
There are plenty of sample codes out there for linked lists in C.

Comment: Thanks you man , and thanks to also everyone who replied to my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem (origin of the error message):

```
list_insert_up(list_t *ptr,int value){
    *ptr=allocate(ptr); // left hand: list_t, right hand: list_t *
    ...
}
```

When you put the `*` before ptr you dereferencing it. You try to set the *value* of `ptr` to a pointer, since `allocate()` returns a pointer (this riggers the error msg). I don't say there are not other issues in the code.

You need something like this:

```
list_insert_up(list_t **ptr,int value){
    *ptr=allocate(*ptr);
    (*ptr)->val=value;
    (*ptr)->next=head;
    head=*ptr;
}
```

Why do you need something like this? Because you want to change the pointer (an address) not the value where the pointer points on.

Comment: if I remove the * before ptr , it compiles, but when in the main , I call the list_insert_up function with the argoment 2 , and then I print the list I get the value 1 , that I insert before

Comment: I updated my answer, is it clear? I tried to run it too, it works (as you want) as long as you call the function like this: list_insert_up(&ptr,2);

Answer (score 0):

Change your `list_insert_up()` function to this:

```
list_t*
list_insert_up(list_t **ptr,int value){
    (*ptr)=allocate(*ptr);
    (*ptr)->val=value;
    (*ptr)->next=head;
    head=*ptr;
}
```

then, call this function this way `list_insert_up(&ptr,2);` in your `main()` function.
You'll get the right answer, because you wanna change the value of a pointer, so you need to pass a pointer pointed to this pointer as argument. Or you can choose to return it instead.

Comment: You are explaining that when passing a pointer as an parameter to a function the function receives a *copy of* the original pointer and that to have any changes to a pointer visible back in the caller, you must pass the *address of* the pointer?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, exactly.